# making a blank(non nil) tviRoom object for delegate function testing

Tags: swift, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I am creating a test case, which tests if the delegate function didDisconnectwithError can be called, for TVIroom class. for that I need to pass the delegate function a blankempty TVI room object. However the delegate function does not accept nil values as inputs, and forced unwrapping is not allowed. 
How do I pass a TVIroom object to the delegate for testing, if it can't be nil?
here is my code so far:

```
func testDisconnectCalled_usedWhileSwitching_AndwhileExplicitlyDisconnecting() {
        let delegate = RoomTestsDelegate()
        let room: TVIRoom? = nil
        let error: Error? = nil

        delegate.room(room, didDisconnectWithError: error)
        expect(delegate.notifiedAboutDidDisconnect).toEventually(beTrue(), timeout: 1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [class reference](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.0.0-beta2/docs/Classes/TVIRoom.html#//api/name/init) of `TVIRoom`, it says that it is **not recommended** to be initialized by developers.

You could, however, create a mocked class similar to `TVIRoom` and set the delegate appropriately.

Comment: how do I do that? some more insight would be helpful